# jQuery populate dropdown depending on the value of another dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
jQuery('select#pickup_location').on('change', function () {
  var selected = jQuery('#pickup_location option:selected').text();

  if (selected == 'The Ascent - 831 Park Ave, Murfreesboro, TN 37129 (5PM-10PM)') {
    jQuery('select#shipping_method_0').text('Pick Up - The Ascent - 831 Park Ave, Murfreesboro, TN 37129 (5PM-10PM) $0.00');
  } else if (selected=='Music City Fitness - 101 Creekside Crossing #600, Brentwood, TN 37027 (5PM-6PM)') {
    jQuery('select#shipping_method_0').text('Pick Up - Music City Fitness - 101 Creekside Crossing #600, Brentwood, TN 37027 (5PM-6PM) $0.00');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr class="shipping">
  <p class="form-row form-row " id="pickup_location_field" data-rules="" data-rules-action="" data-validations="">
  <label for="pickup_location" class="">Pick Up Location</label>
  <select name="pickup_location" id="pickup_location" class="select thwcfe-input-field thwcfe-enhanced-select" data-allow_clear="true" data-placeholder="Please choose a pick up location">
    <option value="" selected='selected'></option>
    <option value="flat_rate:12">The Ascent - 831 Park Ave, Murfreesboro, TN 37129 (5PM-10PM)</option>
    <option value="flat_rate:14">Music City Fitness - 101 Creekside Crossing #600, Brentwood, TN 37027 (5PM-6PM)</option>
    <option value="flat_rate:15">Title Boxing East Nashville - 605 Gallatin Ave, Nashville, TN 37206 (4PM - 7PM)</option>
  </select>
</p>
  
  <th>Shipping</th>
  <td>
    <select name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0" class="shipping_method">
      <option value="">Select Shipping Method</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:1" >Delivery: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#036;</span>5.95</span></option>
      <option value="flat_rate:12"  selected='selected'>Pick Up - The Ascent - 831 Park Ave, Murfreesboro, TN 37129 (5PM-10PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:14" >Pick Up - Music City Fitness - 101 Creekside Crossing #600, Brentwood, TN 37027 (5PM-6PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:15" >Pick Up - Title Boxing East Nashville - 605 Gallatin Ave, Nashville, TN 37206 (4PM - 7PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:16" >Pick Up - 9 Round Fitness - 1050 Glenbrook Way #310, Hendersonville, TN 37075 (4PM-8PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:18" >Pick Up - Bar Method - 4301 Harding Pike, Nashville, TN 37205 (5PM - 6:30PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:19" >Pick Up - Title Boxing Cool Springs - 1550 W McEwen Dr, Franklin, TN 37067 (4PM - 8PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:34" >Pick Up - Eat Well Kitchen - 500 Interstate Blvd S, Lobby, Nashville, TN 37210 (11:00AM - 5PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:38" >Pick Up - 360 Fitness Coaching - 3744 Annex Ave, A3, Nashville, TN 37209 (4PM - 7PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:40" >Grind Fitness - 1310 Antioch Pike #D Nashville, TN 37211 (4PM - 6PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:32" >Pick Up (Sunday) - Crossfit Combustion - 133 Locke Ave, Spring Hill, TN 37174 (3PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:33" >Pick Up (Sunday) - Title Boxing Cool Springs - 1550 W McEwen Dr, Franklin, TN 37067 (6:30PM - 7PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="advanced_free_shipping" >Free Delivery($0.00)</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I have two drop downs that already have data in them. I'd like to populate the second field with one of the options already available based on an option from the first drop down. All the tutorials I've seen don't take into account if the data is already there.

```
jQuery('select#pickup_location').on('change', function () {
  var selected = jQuery('#pickup_location option:selected').text();

  if (selected == 'The Ascent - 831 Park Ave, Murfreesboro, TN 37129 (5PM-10PM)') {
    jQuery('select#shipping_method_0').text('Pick Up - The Ascent - 831 Park Ave, Murfreesboro, TN 37129 (5PM-10PM) $0.00');
  } else if (selected=='Music City Fitness - 101 Creekside Crossing #600, Brentwood, TN 37027 (5PM-6PM)') {
    jQuery('select#shipping_method_0').text('Pick Up - Music City Fitness - 101 Creekside Crossing #600, Brentwood, TN 37027 (5PM-6PM) $0.00');
  }
});
```

This is what I have so far, I know for a fact it isn't wrong, but I don't know where or how to fix or simplify it. Here is the HTML for both drop downs.

```
<p class="form-row form-row " id="pickup_location_field" data-rules="" data-rules-action="" data-validations="">
  <label for="pickup_location" class="">Pick Up Location</label>
  <select name="pickup_location" id="pickup_location" class="select thwcfe-input-field thwcfe-enhanced-select" data-allow_clear="true" data-placeholder="Please choose a pick up location">
    <option value="" selected='selected'></option>
    <option value="flat_rate:12">The Ascent - 831 Park Ave, Murfreesboro, TN 37129 (5PM-10PM)</option>
    <option value="flat_rate:14">Music City Fitness - 101 Creekside Crossing #600, Brentwood, TN 37027 (5PM-6PM)</option>
    <option value="flat_rate:15">Title Boxing East Nashville - 605 Gallatin Ave, Nashville, TN 37206 (4PM - 7PM)</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

And here is the second drop down:

```
<tr class="shipping">
  <th>Shipping</th>
  <td>
    <select name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0" class="shipping_method">
      <option value="">Select Shipping Method</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:1" >Delivery: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#036;</span>5.95</span></option>
      <option value="flat_rate:12"  selected='selected'>Pick Up - The Ascent - 831 Park Ave, Murfreesboro, TN 37129 (5PM-10PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:14" >Pick Up - Music City Fitness - 101 Creekside Crossing #600, Brentwood, TN 37027 (5PM-6PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:15" >Pick Up - Title Boxing East Nashville - 605 Gallatin Ave, Nashville, TN 37206 (4PM - 7PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:16" >Pick Up - 9 Round Fitness - 1050 Glenbrook Way #310, Hendersonville, TN 37075 (4PM-8PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:18" >Pick Up - Bar Method - 4301 Harding Pike, Nashville, TN 37205 (5PM - 6:30PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:19" >Pick Up - Title Boxing Cool Springs - 1550 W McEwen Dr, Franklin, TN 37067 (4PM - 8PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:34" >Pick Up - Eat Well Kitchen - 500 Interstate Blvd S, Lobby, Nashville, TN 37210 (11:00AM - 5PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:38" >Pick Up - 360 Fitness Coaching - 3744 Annex Ave, A3, Nashville, TN 37209 (4PM - 7PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:40" >Grind Fitness - 1310 Antioch Pike #D Nashville, TN 37211 (4PM - 6PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:32" >Pick Up (Sunday) - Crossfit Combustion - 133 Locke Ave, Spring Hill, TN 37174 (3PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:33" >Pick Up (Sunday) - Title Boxing Cool Springs - 1550 W McEwen Dr, Franklin, TN 37067 (6:30PM - 7PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="advanced_free_shipping" >Free Delivery($0.00)</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Kyle man, what is the goal? Do you want to select the shipping method only for some of the pickup locations? Please explain what you want to achieve. Do you want to assign and show only specific shipping methods based on pickup location??

Comment: I've altered my code to disable the second drop down.

Answer (score 0):

`.text()` will set the `textContent` but here you want to use the `html()` function and wrap the text inside an `<option></option>` tag then only it'll render inside the `select`

```js
jQuery('select#pickup_location').on('change', function () {
  var selected = jQuery('#pickup_location option:selected').text();

  if (selected == 'The Ascent - 831 Park Ave, Murfreesboro, TN 37129 (5PM-10PM)') {
    jQuery('select#shipping_method_0').html('<option>Pick Up - The Ascent - 831 Park Ave, Murfreesboro, TN 37129 (5PM-10PM) $0.00</option>');
  } else if (selected=='Music City Fitness - 101 Creekside Crossing #600, Brentwood, TN 37027 (5PM-6PM)') {
    jQuery('select#shipping_method_0').html('<option>Pick Up - Music City Fitness - 101 Creekside Crossing #600, Brentwood, TN 37027 (5PM-6PM) $0.00</option>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr class="shipping">
  <p class="form-row form-row " id="pickup_location_field" data-rules="" data-rules-action="" data-validations="">
  <label for="pickup_location" class="">Pick Up Location</label>
  <select name="pickup_location" id="pickup_location" class="select thwcfe-input-field thwcfe-enhanced-select" data-allow_clear="true" data-placeholder="Please choose a pick up location">
    <option value="" selected='selected'></option>
    <option value="flat_rate:12">The Ascent - 831 Park Ave, Murfreesboro, TN 37129 (5PM-10PM)</option>
    <option value="flat_rate:14">Music City Fitness - 101 Creekside Crossing #600, Brentwood, TN 37027 (5PM-6PM)</option>
    <option value="flat_rate:15">Title Boxing East Nashville - 605 Gallatin Ave, Nashville, TN 37206 (4PM - 7PM)</option>
  </select>
</p>
  
  <th>Shipping</th>
  <td>
    <select name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0" class="shipping_method">
      <option value="">Select Shipping Method</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:1" >Delivery: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#036;</span>5.95</span></option>
      <option value="flat_rate:12"  selected='selected'>Pick Up - The Ascent - 831 Park Ave, Murfreesboro, TN 37129 (5PM-10PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:14" >Pick Up - Music City Fitness - 101 Creekside Crossing #600, Brentwood, TN 37027 (5PM-6PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:15" >Pick Up - Title Boxing East Nashville - 605 Gallatin Ave, Nashville, TN 37206 (4PM - 7PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:16" >Pick Up - 9 Round Fitness - 1050 Glenbrook Way #310, Hendersonville, TN 37075 (4PM-8PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:18" >Pick Up - Bar Method - 4301 Harding Pike, Nashville, TN 37205 (5PM - 6:30PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:19" >Pick Up - Title Boxing Cool Springs - 1550 W McEwen Dr, Franklin, TN 37067 (4PM - 8PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:34" >Pick Up - Eat Well Kitchen - 500 Interstate Blvd S, Lobby, Nashville, TN 37210 (11:00AM - 5PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:38" >Pick Up - 360 Fitness Coaching - 3744 Annex Ave, A3, Nashville, TN 37209 (4PM - 7PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:40" >Grind Fitness - 1310 Antioch Pike #D Nashville, TN 37211 (4PM - 6PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:32" >Pick Up (Sunday) - Crossfit Combustion - 133 Locke Ave, Spring Hill, TN 37174 (3PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:33" >Pick Up (Sunday) - Title Boxing Cool Springs - 1550 W McEwen Dr, Franklin, TN 37067 (6:30PM - 7PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="advanced_free_shipping" >Free Delivery($0.00)</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You're replacing the entire contents of the drop down, and destroying them.  That does not seem to be what OP is after.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! So then if I wanted to populate a text field, I would use the .text()?

Comment: Not only that, but if the text of those options changes, you have to change it in 3 places.  This answer is horribly wrong.

Comment: This is actually fine for what I'm after. I don't want them to change the second drop down.

Comment: @SeanKendle I think that is what OP want because when the user selected a location, an option to ship other place is not logical

Comment: If the user selects any other location after selecting one of those two, they get no other option but picking it up.

Comment: `text()` will set the textContent but `html` will set the innerHTML

Comment: If you selected NY as primary location, then showing CA under NY is obviously wrong don't you think so @SeanKendle

Comment: Yes, which is why you use validation, you don't destroy every other selection in the textbox.   And you have the text hard coded in for the selections, so if they change even slightly it break the code.  So someone selects something on accident, whoops, they can't make any other selection.

Comment: Select one of the top two, then select the third one.  Doesn't change. Your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

create a javascript object and map the value of second drop down to first drop down and define js function as below. It is the simplest method without multiple if else.

```
var obj = {
     "flat_rate:12" : "flat_rate:12",
   "flat_rate:14" : "flat_rate:14",
   "flat_rate:15" : "flat_rate:15"
}

jQuery('select#pickup_location').on('change', function () {
  var selected = jQuery('#pickup_location option:selected').val();
  jQuery('select#shipping_method_0').val(obj[selected]);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so you're trying to set the `text()` of a drop down, but what you should be doing is setting its `val()`:

```js
//Simplified:  Check the val() (this will change less than the text, and it's harder to make a mistake with the val, as it's shorter!)
jQuery('select#pickup_location').on('change', function () {
  var selected = jQuery('#pickup_location option:selected').val();

  //both drop down lists have the same val's, so use that!
  if (selected == 'flat_rate:12' || selected== 'flat_rate:14') {
    jQuery('select#shipping_method_0').val(selected ).attr("disabled", "disabled");

  } else {
    //what if they select one, then select something different?
    //maybe set it back to the top selection?
    jQuery('select#shipping_method_0').val("").removeAttr("disabled");

  }
});
```

```html
<!-- Don't forget to include jQuery in your snippets!-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tr class="shipping">
  <p class="form-row form-row " id="pickup_location_field" data-rules="" data-rules-action="" data-validations="">
  <label for="pickup_location" class="">Pick Up Location</label>
  <select name="pickup_location" id="pickup_location" class="select thwcfe-input-field thwcfe-enhanced-select" data-allow_clear="true" data-placeholder="Please choose a pick up location">
    <option value="" selected='selected'></option>
    <option value="flat_rate:12">The Ascent - 831 Park Ave, Murfreesboro, TN 37129 (5PM-10PM)</option>
    <option value="flat_rate:14">Music City Fitness - 101 Creekside Crossing #600, Brentwood, TN 37027 (5PM-6PM)</option>
    <option value="flat_rate:15">Title Boxing East Nashville - 605 Gallatin Ave, Nashville, TN 37206 (4PM - 7PM)</option>
  </select>
</p>
  
  <th>Shipping</th>
  <td>
    <select name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0" class="shipping_method">
      <option value="">Select Shipping Method</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:1" >Delivery: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#036;</span>5.95</span></option>
      <option value="flat_rate:12"  selected='selected'>Pick Up - The Ascent - 831 Park Ave, Murfreesboro, TN 37129 (5PM-10PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:14" >Pick Up - Music City Fitness - 101 Creekside Crossing #600, Brentwood, TN 37027 (5PM-6PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:15" >Pick Up - Title Boxing East Nashville - 605 Gallatin Ave, Nashville, TN 37206 (4PM - 7PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:16" >Pick Up - 9 Round Fitness - 1050 Glenbrook Way #310, Hendersonville, TN 37075 (4PM-8PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:18" >Pick Up - Bar Method - 4301 Harding Pike, Nashville, TN 37205 (5PM - 6:30PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:19" >Pick Up - Title Boxing Cool Springs - 1550 W McEwen Dr, Franklin, TN 37067 (4PM - 8PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:34" >Pick Up - Eat Well Kitchen - 500 Interstate Blvd S, Lobby, Nashville, TN 37210 (11:00AM - 5PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:38" >Pick Up - 360 Fitness Coaching - 3744 Annex Ave, A3, Nashville, TN 37209 (4PM - 7PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:40" >Grind Fitness - 1310 Antioch Pike #D Nashville, TN 37211 (4PM - 6PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:32" >Pick Up (Sunday) - Crossfit Combustion - 133 Locke Ave, Spring Hill, TN 37174 (3PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="flat_rate:33" >Pick Up (Sunday) - Title Boxing Cool Springs - 1550 W McEwen Dr, Franklin, TN 37067 (6:30PM - 7PM) $0.00</option>
      <option value="advanced_free_shipping" >Free Delivery($0.00)</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If the person selected location then showing other locations in the secondary box is not populating it's just changing which OP doesn't want actually

Comment: There, I've disabled the second drop down where it makes sense.

Comment: disabling is not an option you should restrict others being selected. but i've retracted my vote

Comment: I like this, thank you! Now, if I needed to take only the address part of that and populate a text field, I could do that as well, right?

Comment: @SeanKendle, would you be able to show me how to get a selected option as two different strings so that I can populate a couple fields? For example, I need to get the company name as one string to populate a company name field, and the address as a second string to populate an address field

Comment: You can use data tags on the options, potentially, to grab that information:  

`<option data-company="Company Name" val="Value">Option Text</option>`

`jQuery("#textboxId").val(jQuery('#pickup_location option:selected').data('company'));`

Do the same with `data-address` and `.data('address')`

Comment: Or, you can use a RegEx if you know you'll *always* separate the company name from the address with a `|` or a `-` or something, but this is not as certain if you type something wrong or mess up your syntax.  Plus, it's more work and more code.

Comment: @SeanKendle, I can't use data tags bc the dropdown was created with a plugin within woocommerce. Here is what I have so far:
jQuery('select#pickup_location').on('change', function () {
  var adr = jQuery('#pickup_location').find('option:selected').text();
    if (adr == 'flat_rate:12' || adr == 'flat_rate:15' || adr == 'flat_rate:18' || adr == 'flat_rate:19' || adr == 'flat_rate:34'){
      var fields = jQuery(adr.split(','));
       var comp = jQuery(fields[0]);
       var street = jQuery(fields[1]);
       var city = jQuery(fields[2]);
       var zip = jQuery(fields[3]);
}

Comment: This might be better suited as a new question.